# update old docker image to the new version of the docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a old docker image which is  this

[old image](https://hub.docker.com/r/delaugustin/sra-toolkit/tags)
I pulled the image

```
docker pull delaugustin/sra-toolkit:2.11.3
```

The lastest ncbi sra build which is [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/ncbi/sra-tools/tags)

So i pull this image as well

```
docker pull ncbi/sra-tools:latest
```

My objective is to update the old sra-toolkit:2.11.3 to the sra-tool:latest.

In order to do that I created a docker file which is like this since I didn't have  to the original docker file

```
cat Dockerfile
FROM ncbi/sra-tools:3.0.1

# Set general socket behavior timeouts
# Set general socket behavior timeouts
RUN vdb-config -s /libs/kns/connect/timeout=5000 --root
RUN vdb-config  -s /libs/kns/connect/timeout/read=1000 --root
RUN vdb-config  -s /libs/kns/connect/timeout/write=1000 --root

# Set HTTP-specific timeout values
RUN vdb-config -s /http/timeout/read=10000 --root
RUN vdb-config -s /http/timeout/write=1000 --root
```

The issue which I faced later when i ran it the new image is failing when it is ran through a workflow, but the older image works fine.

What i observed when I compared both the containers folder structure is in the older version there are lot more things as compared to the new image which I created.

So now is there a way where i can simply update the delaugustin/sra-toolkit:2.11.3 to the newest build of sra-tool:latest where all the contents of the delaugustin/sra-toolkit:2.11.3 remains at the same time it incorporates the newest fixes or features that is available  in the latest build.

Any help or suggestion would be really helpful.